# PHP create array from xml with recursive method

Tags: php, arrays, xml

Need to fulfill a recursive function that can accept also a second child node, i have tried to loop the second foreach but i cannot achieve it. maybe im missing somenthing and wondering if anyone has passed trough this:

The code is:

```
function runXml() {

        $content1 = <<< XML
<data>
    <users>
        <user>
            <name>myName</name>
            <email>myEmail</email>
            <address>MyAddres - City - Country</address>
        </user>
        <user>
            <name>myName2</name>
            <email>myEmail2</email>
            <address>MyAddres2 - City - Country</address>
        </user>
    </users>
</data>
XML;

        $content2 = <<< XML
    <users>
        <user>
            <name>myName</name>
            <email>myEmail</email>
            <address>MyAddres - City - Country</address>
        </user>
        <user>
            <name>myName2</name>
            <email>myEmail2</email>
            <address>MyAddres2 - City - Country</address>
        </user>
    </users>
XML;

        echo '<pre>';
        $xml1 = simplexml_load_string($content1);
        print_r($this->processFeedXmlWithoutAttributes($xml1));

        $xml2 = simplexml_load_string($content2);
        print_r($this->processFeedXmlWithoutAttributes($xml2));

    }

    function processFeedXmlWithoutAttributes($xml)
    {
        $output = array();
        try {
            if($xml->children()) {
                $children = $xml->children();
                if(count($children) > 0) {
                    foreach($children as $child) {
                        $output[] = $child;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
        }
        return $output;
    }
```

The result is:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [user] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [name] => myName
                            [email] => myEmail
                            [address] => MyAddres - City - Country
                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [name] => myName2
                            [email] => myEmail2
                            [address] => MyAddres2 - City - Country
                        )

                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [name] => myName
            [email] => myEmail
            [address] => MyAddres - City - Country
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [name] => myName2
            [email] => myEmail2
            [address] => MyAddres2 - City - Country
        )

)
```

The desired result is for both structure of xml:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [name] => myName
            [email] => myEmail
            [address] => MyAddres - City - Country
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [name] => myName2
            [email] => myEmail2
            [address] => MyAddres2 - City - Country
        )

)
```

For the first structure where i have "" user index is being added and a multidimensional array is created, the idea is to get rid of that index and get the array to be itered later.

Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes to the fact that `user` node should be the root in both case.

In order to achieve it - you can start parsing XML from this node. Possible solution for `processFeedXmlWithoutAttributes` method:

```
    function processFeedXmlWithoutAttributes(\SimpleXMLElement $xml): array
    {
        $output = [];
        try {
            while ($xml->getName() !== 'user') {
                $xml = $xml->children();
            }
            foreach ($xml as $child) {
                $output[] = $child;
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
        }

        return $output;
    }
```

Comment: yes, i understand that :), the idea is to get the same recursive code for both options, the user nodename is dynamic, i would like to hard code the nodename, but i cannot since i have about 40 xmls with different node names.